# Yii2, custom validation: clientValidateAttribute() doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-validation

I have form, created by ActiveForm widget. User enters polish postal code there. In appropriate controller I put entered data in DB, for example:

```
$company_profile_data->postal_code = $_POST['CompanyProfiles']['postal_code'];
$company_profile_data->update();
```

I decided to use standalone validator for postal code validation. *Rules for this attribute in model*:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        //...some other rules...
        ['postal_code', 'string', 'length' => [6,6]],
        ['postal_code', PostalValidator::className()], //standalone validator
    ];
}
```

*app/components/validators/PostalValidator class code*:

```
namespace app\components\validators;

use yii\validators\Validator;
use app\models\CompanyProfiles;
use app\models\Users;

class PostalValidator extends Validator {
    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute) {

    if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}$/', $model->$attribute))
        $model->addError($attribute, 'Wrong postal code format.');
    }

public function clientValidateAttribute($model, $attribute, $view) { //want js-validation too
    $message = 'Invalid status input.';
    return <<<JS
if (!/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}$/.test("{$model->$attribute}")) {
    messages.push("$message");
}
JS;
    }
}
```

So, an example of correct code is *00-202*.

When I (in user role) enter incorrect value, page reloads and I see `Wrong postal code format.` message, although I redefined `clientValidateAttribute` method and wrote `JS-validation`, which, as I suggested, will not allow page to reload. Then I press submit button again: this time page doesn't reload and I see `Invalid status input.` message (so, the second press time JS triggers). But I when enter correct code after that, I still see `Invalid status input.` message and nothing happens.

So, what's wrong with my `clientValidateAttribute()` method? `validateAttribute()` works great.

**UPDATE**
*Snippet from controller*

```
public function actionProfile(){ //can't use massive assignment here, cause info from 2 (not 1) user models is needed
    if (\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->redirect('/site/index/');
    }
    $is_user_admin = Users::findOne(['is_admin' => 1]);
    if ($is_user_admin->id == \Yii::$app->user->id)
        return $this->redirect('/admin/login/');

    $is_user_blocked = Users::find()->where(['is_blocked' => 1, 'id' => \Yii::$app->user->id])->one();
    if($is_user_blocked)
        return $this->actionLogout();

//3 model instances to retrieve data from users && company_profiles && logo
    $user_data = Users::find()->where(['id'=>\Yii::$app->user->id])->one();
    $user_data->scenario = 'update';

    $company_profile_data = CompanyProfiles::find()->where(['user_id'=>Yii::$app->user->id])->one();
    $logo = LogoData::findOne(['user_id' => \Yii::$app->user->id]);
    $logo_name = $logo->logo_name; //will be NULL, if user have never uploaded logo. In this case placeholder will be used

    $upload_logo = new UploadLogo();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {

        $upload_logo->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($upload_logo, 'imageFile');

        if ($upload_logo->imageFile) { //1st part ($logo_data->imageFile) - whether user have uploaded logo
            $logo_file_name = md5($user_data->id);
            $is_uploaded = $upload_logo->upload($logo_file_name);
            if ($is_uploaded) { //this cond is needed, cause validation for image fails (?)
                //create record in 'logo_data' tbl, deleting previous
                if ($logo_name) {
                    $logo->delete();
                } else { //if upload logo first time, set val to $logo_name. Otherwise NULL val will pass to 'profile' view, and user wont see his new logo at once
                    $logo_name = $logo_file_name.'.'.$upload_logo->imageFile->extension;
                }
                $logo_data = new LogoData;
                $logo_data->user_id = \Yii::$app->user->id;
                $logo_data->logo_name = $logo_name;
                $logo_data->save();
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['CompanyProfiles'])){

        $company_profile_data->firm_data = $_POST['CompanyProfiles']['firm_data'];
        $company_profile_data->company_name = $_POST['CompanyProfiles']['company_name'];
        $company_profile_data->regon = $_POST['CompanyProfiles']['regon'];
        $company_profile_data->pesel = $_POST['CompanyProfiles']['pesel'];
        $company_profile_data->postal_code = $_POST['CompanyProfiles']['postal_code'];
        $company_profile_data->nip = $_POST['CompanyProfiles']['nip'];
        $company_profile_data->country = $_POST['CompanyProfiles']['country'];
        $company_profile_data->city = $_POST['CompanyProfiles']['city'];
        $company_profile_data->address = $_POST['CompanyProfiles']['address'];
        $company_profile_data->telephone_num = $_POST['CompanyProfiles']['telephone_num'];
        $company_profile_data->email = $_POST['CompanyProfiles']['email'];          
        $company_profile_data->update();
    }

    if (isset($_POST['personal-data-button'])) {
        $user_data->username = $_POST['Users']['username'];
        $user_data->password_repeat = $user_data->password = md5($_POST['Users']['password']);
        $user_data->update();
    }
    return $this->render('profile', ['user_data' => $user_data, 'company_profile_data' => $company_profile_data, 'upload_logo' => $upload_logo, 'logo_name' => $logo_name]);
}
```

Comment: You are using load function? I suppose that load called only after submit form.

Comment: No, I don't use it. I do this (as I wrote above):`$company_profile_data->postal_code = $_POST['CompanyProfiles']['postal_code']`. So, I don't use massive assignment. You see, other attributes validate correctly (before submitting) without any `load()`. But not in case of standalone validation.

Comment: I thing problem in controller. You can update post with contoller code?

Comment: Sure. Just in case I added **all** `actionProfile` code, but, I think, the most interesting part is in `IF` stmt: `if (isset($_POST['CompanyProfiles'])){...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My inaccuracy was in `clientValidateAttribute()` method. Instead of `$model->$attribute` in code snippet:

```
if (!/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}$/.test("{$model->$attribute}")) {
```

...I had to use predefined JS-var [value](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#clientValidateAttribute()-detail), cause this var changes with entered value change. So, my new code is:

```
public function clientValidateAttribute($model, $attribute, $view) {
    return <<<JS
if (!/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}$/.test(value)) {
    messages.push("Wrong postal code format.");
} 
JS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Model does not load rules and behaviors until [not called any function](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Component.php#L277) from model. When you call `$company_profile_data->update();` model call `update` and `validate` functions.

Try add after `$company_profile_data = CompanyProfiles::find()` this code:

```
$company_profile_data->validate();
```

Or just use `load` function. I think it will help.

Comment: No success in both cases. But, I think, I have resolved the problem. Thanks for participating. :)